# What's the phrase that is used with 'honest' to indicate sarcasm that I am being monitored

Tags: phrases, idioms

What's it that is used with 'honest' to indicate sarcasm that I am being monitored.

.

Comment: I don’t understand what you are asking. Something to keep you honest, perhaps?

Comment: There is some kind of phrase which means that some one is always keeping an eye on you and correcting you

Comment: There are many such phrases. But what does that have to do with honesty? If it is about honesty, use tchrist's suggestion.

Comment: Do you mean- in spite of being honest......

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the phrase *keeping one honest*.  It indicates oversight of some sort.

[Here](http://www.statesmanexaminer.com/content/sophie%E2%80%99s-choice-thanks-keeping-me-honest) is a columnist  saying, "Sophie’s Choice: Thanks for keeping me honest", and an English teacher [with](http://teachingwithteachers.com/2015/02/08/writing-keeping-me-honest/) "Writing... keeping me honest"

Comment: Sounds good, can you cite some sources? Is that well known?

Comment: Can you cite some examples